# Casting int function to void*

Tags: c, linux, void-pointers

I have a problem with casting returned integer value to void pointer. Have tried some options from this site but my problem seems to still haven't been resolved. Although the program compiles with no code errors I'm getting a segmentation fault. Am I blind and are there some mistakes in my code?

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int ackermann(int a, int b)
{
    if(a==0)
        return a+1;
    else if(a>0 && b==0)
    {
        return ackermann(a-1, 1);
    }
    else if(a>0 && b>0)
    {
        return ackermann(a-1,ackermann(a,(b-1)));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int c = ackermann(a,b);
    void *ptr = &c;
    pthread_t mythread;
    if(pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, ptr, NULL))
    {
        printf("Could not create a thread\n");
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/AMD4k0

Comment: Hint: why waste `argc`?

Comment: The third parameter of `pthread_create`  is a pointer to function (in this case `ackerman`), but you are passing a pointer to `int`

Comment: Which function do you want to call with `pthread_create`?

Comment: Alter Mann is right: the line `int c = ackermann(a,b);` launches the function, calculates the result and stores it in an integer. When you perform pthread_create ptr points to the integer `c` - you're trying to launch the integer, not the function, and the calculation has long ended, in the main thread.

Comment: Why do you need a thread here ??

Comment: I wrote a script in bash, that generates 2 random numbers, and compares a time of execution of this program by using both thread and fork(). Thanks for answers, I'll try to cast it properly.

Comment: @MichalHabigier, no, don't cast, just pass the function as third parameter, and if you need to to pass `a` and `b`, put those variables into a `struct` and pass a pointer to this `struct` as last parameter (excuse my poor english) .e.g: `if(pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, ackermann, &the_struct))`, `ackermann` must receive a `void *` instead of 2 `int`s

Comment: @MichalHabigier, or you can pass an array of 2 `int`s, that's simpler: `if(pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, ackermann, (int[2]){atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])}))`

Comment: Try using something like `gdb` or `valgrind` so that you can find exactly where your program is breaking...

Comment: What does this call `int ackermann(-1, 0)` return?  Maybe 42?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you're not actually calling the function `ackermann` in a separate thread.  What you are doing is calling the function directly from `main`, storing the result in an `int`, and passing a pointer to that `int` as the third parameter to `pthread_create`, which is supposed to be a pointer to the function to run.

Right now, `ackermann` does not have the appropriate signature to be passed to `pthread_create`.  A function that starts a new thread should be declared like this:

```
void *my_thread_function(void *parameter);
```

Given that `ackermann` is called recursively, it would be cleaner to pass a  a wrapper function to `pthread_create` and have that wrapper call `ackermann` rather than modifying `ackermann` to match the above signature.

Because you need to pass multiple parameters to your thread function, you'll need to create a `struct` which contains all the parameters and pass a pointer to that `struct` to thread function.

You can also store the return value in this struct so that the function which started the thread has access to it.

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int ackermann(int a, int b)
{
    if(a==0) {
        return a+1;
    } else if(a>0 && b==0) {
        return ackermann(a-1, 1);
    } else if(a>0 && b>0) {
        return ackermann(a-1,ackermann(a,(b-1)));
    }
    // if none of the above conditions are true, no value is returned
    // better check for this
}

struct ackermann_params {
    int a;
    int b;
    int result;
};

void *ackermann_thr(void *arg)
{
    struct ackermann_params *params = arg;
    params->result = ackermann(params->a, params->b);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct ackermann_params params;
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("invalid number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    params.a = atoi(argv[1]);
    params.b = atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t mythread;
    if(pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, ackermann_thr, &params))
    {
        perror("Could not create a thread\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pthread_join(mythread, NULL)) {
        perror("join failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("result=%d\n", params.result);

    return 0;
}
```